# ftruncate() not emptying my file

Tags: php, truncate

I have a file in which I write

```
<timestamp>hashedcertificate
<timestamp>hashedcertificate
<timestamp>hashedcertificate
```

(etc.)

On a certain request, I'm reading out all timestamps in an array and all hash strings in an array.

```
$valid = fopen("./valid", "r+");
if (!$valid) {
  log::Write("Could not open file. Exiting..", DEBUG);
  exit(1);
}
$isLocked = flock($valid, LOCK_EX);
while (!$isLocked)
  $isLocked = flock($valid, LOCK_EX);
while (!feof($valid)) {
  $pos_begin = strpos($line, "<");
  $pos_end = strpos($line, ">", $pos_begin);
  $timestamp = substr($line, $pos_begin+1, $pos_end - $pos_begin - 1);
  $timestamps[] = $timestamp;
  $storedCert = substr($line, $pos_end + 1);
  $storedCerts[] = $storedCert;
  log::Write(sprintf("Read: %s with timestamp %s", $storedCert, $timestamp), DEBUG);
  $line = fgets($valid);
}
```

After checking them (remove if timestamp is too old), I want to write back the remaining, valid hashes back into the file.

```
ftruncate($valid, 0);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($timestamps as $timestamp) {
  $toWrite = "<" . $timestamp . ">" . $storedCerts[$counter] . "\n";
  log::Write(sprintf("Writing: \n%s", $toWrite), DEBUG);
  fputs($valid, $toWrite);
  $counter += 1;
}
flock($valid, LOCK_UN);
fclose($valid);
```

But my file does always look like this: (after the ftruncate I think, because when I open the file to append the timestamps+hash, it does that without strange stuff; only when the reading from file + remove array elements + ftruncate + write back into file stuff comes)
(please ignore the first hash; i changed it temporary to crc32 to have it shorter):

^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<1378903136>9f71fb266d96afa161c1e52e8b65031c08997bdb5f215f7d

```
<1378903666>b0e15296
<1378903671>6b4132b9
<1378903695>b0e15296
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you do a rewind() after the truncate to reset the pointer to the beginning of the file again?

Comment: That was it, I didn't know that (PHP beginner since 2 weeks :)) Thank you very much!